# How do I remove mineral stains from tiles?

Tags: tile, removal

The water in our apartment has higher salt levels, which ultimately makes stains on tile.  I tried to remove them with various bleaching agents, but with no effect.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would suggest you try CLR.  It is available in most stores and hardware stores.  If this doesn't work, my question would be what type of tile do you have? Almost sounds like you may have an unglazed type of tile, not a highly glazed porcelain. If you are successful cleaning the tile, you may want to seal the tile to help in the future. You can find tile and grout sealers at any home center.

.

Comment: White vinegar is another option. It's much less potent (and won't do as good a job as CLR), but safer.

Comment: let me first try with white vinegar , if it fails i will use clr

Comment: thanks for the idea of sealing the tiles, yes ours is unsealed one only.